# Creating index takes more time than dropping in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I've created an index in database in SQL:[image]
It took 124ms to get created.

Where when I drop that index:[image: Image2]
It took 74ms.

Why creating takes much more time than dropping?

Comment: This is live, it is easier to tear down than to build up.

Comment: What do you think is faster: scanning the whole table, sorting the values and writing a tree data structure or deleting a file from disk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplified explanation... creating an index is more than just creating a database object. There are calculations and data copies being performed on the initial creation and any time the data in the indexed columns gets changed. Dropping an index simply releases that object and its associated data. As a result, the larger amount of data involved in the indexed columns the longer it will take to create that index.